# How to delete all values from sorted set which are part of different unsorted set

Tags: python, lua, redis

I am trying to delete using lua script but i don't know what's going wrong

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost',port=6379)
pipe = r.pipeline(transaction = False)
lua = """
local env = redis.call('smembers', 'user_key')
redis.call('zrem','another_key', unpack(env))
"""
p = r.register_script(lua)
p(client=pipe)
```

Comment: I don't see any sets in your code but you can subtract sets i.e `{1,2,3,4,5} - {3,4,5,6,7}` will give you `{1,2}`

Comment: Can you more clearly explain the problem here exactly? What is going wrong exactly? Is the python wrapping here at all relevant to the problem?

Comment: `local` is a keyword in Lua (and there's a comma missing as well). Maybe that's what's going wrong ...

Comment: Yes i know local is reserve keyword, while posting question i made mistake please check now

Comment: Maybe your Redis is too old. The [documentation for ZREM](http://redis.io/commands/ZREM) states that you can only pass multiple arguments on Redis 2.4 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

`local` is reserved [Lua keyword](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html) that's used for declaring local variables. In Redis' Lua scripting engine, all variables must be local to prevent sandbox litter getting out of hand (read the docs at http://redis.io/commands/eval#global-variables-protection)

Your script is simply missing a variable name - the following should probably work better:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost',port=6379)
pipe = r.pipeline(transaction = False)
lua = """
local l = redis.call('smembers' 'user_key')
redis.call('zrem', unpack(l))
"""
p = r.register_script(lua)
p(client=pipe)
```

Also, there's no real need for a pipeline here IMO.

Comment: Yes i know local is reserve keyword, while posting question i made mistake please check now